# Proving that the cubic operation is injective

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider $\mathbb Z_{17}$. I want to prove that if $x^3\equiv y^3 \pmod{17}$ then $x\equiv y \pmod{17}$.

Here's a start:

$$x^3 \equiv y^3 \pmod{17} \\ \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$$

How can I deduce that $x\equiv y \pmod{17}$?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I think I know. Let's denote $r := ord_{17} (\frac{x}{y})$ then $r \mid 3$ and $r  \mid 16$ (by Fermmat's theorem) but $\gcd(3,16)=1$ so $r=1$. so $\frac{x}{y} = 1 \implies x\equiv y \pmod{17}$.

Comment: Hint: $x^{33} \equiv x \pmod{17}$.

Comment: Brute force works (there are only $17$ values to compute).  For a more powerful approach, note that $x^3=y^3$ for non-zero $x,y$ would mean that the multiplicative group has an element of order $3$, so $3$ would have to divide the order of the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), if $x\not\equiv0\pmod{17}$, then $x^{16}\equiv1\pmod{17}$.

If $x^3\equiv1\pmod{17}$, then $x^{16}\equiv x\cdot (x^3)^5\equiv x\equiv1\pmod{17}$. So if $x^3\equiv1\pmod{17}$, then $x\equiv1\pmod{17}$

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice approach, thank you!

Comment: It’s my pleasure to help!